# Is it natural to use verbs that can be used as either an intransitive verb or a transitive verb in the same sentence/paragraph

Tags: verbs

> The room temperature will increase to about 15℃ by noon.  If you feel cool
>   now, you can use an air conditioner to increase it right now.

Does this type of usage of verbs sound natural?

Comment: Yes, the verbs sound fine.  It's perfectly understandable to use a verb in two slightly different senses in the same paragraph.  My only issue is that we don't use an air conditioner to *increase* the temperature of a room.

Comment: It is unclear what "it" refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't ungrammatical, nevertheless, we usually try to avoid repeating the same word in a sentence. If you can rephrase this, you should.

The overall sentence is rather odd.  Fifteen degrees C is rather cool for a room, and an air conditioner is used to make a room cooler (though some A/C also have heater function). The purpose of the sentence isn't clear. You don't need to tell people that they can heat a room with a heater, or that you warming a room is something that you do when you are cold. All you need to do is provide them with the information that isn't obvious: That the room is cold, but the A/C works as a heater.